# In R, how do I add rows containing counts of the number of values in that column that ==x?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
Q1 <- c(1,0,1,4,3)
Q2 <- c(0,1,2,1,4)

df <- data.frame(Q1,Q2)
df

  Q1 Q2
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  1  2
4  4  1
5  3  4
```

There are many more columns like this, and what I want to do is add 5 rows at the bottom of the dataframe with the count of how many items in each column==0, how many ==1, how many ==2, how many==3 and how many==4. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `table` on each column in `df` and `rbind` to original dataset.

```
rbind(df, sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 0:4))))

#   Q1 Q2
#1   1  0
#2   0  1
#3   1  2
#4   4  1
#5   3  4
#0   1  1
#11  2  2
#21  0  1
#31  1  0
#41  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (if it's numeric, make it character or factor in order to get the count of each level)

```
New_df1 <- as.data.frame(table(df$Q1)

New_df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df$Q2)
```

Then you can transform and add (if you want) them to your original data frame.